# How to add a user to Firestore database after signing up through Firebase Authentication?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Upon sign up, I want to add a user to a "users" collection using the corresponding userID. Under this userID would be the user's data, such as name, email, posts, etc...

Here is my code:

I get no errors, and the user is created and is visible in firebase auth. However the user is not added to the firestore database.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(cred => {
  const userId = cred.user.uid;
  const userData = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email
  };
  db.collection("users").doc(userId).set(userData).then(() => {
    console.log("User successfully added to the DB!");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error adding user to the DB: ", e);
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('User created! - ' + email);
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e.message);
  txtErrMsg.classList.remove('hide');
  txtErrMsg.innerHTML = e.message;
});
```

It just seems like I am not able call the DB inside of the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)` function. If I put the `db.collection("users").doc(userId).set(userData)` call with some dummy data outside of the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)` function, then the data appears in the firestore DB.

FYI: I have console logged the parameters (userId and userData), and they appear as expected.

Comment: Can you see any of those `console.log`'s from `set` method?

Comment: No, I can't see any of the console.log's from the set method... Do you know why I can't?